# I can't upgrade cartopy to 0.18.0 using conda

Tags: installation, version, cartopy

I'm trying to upgrade cartopy to version 0.18.0

I tried `conda update cartopy` and it does nothing.

I removed cartopy and tried to reinstall cartopy using `conda install -c conda-forge cartopy` and it tells me that is going to install version 0.17.0 and not 0.18.0.

I finally tried to install it using `pip install cartopy`. PIP tries to install the version 0.18.0 but I get a different error here that I'm not able to solve:
lib/cartopy/trace.cpp(665): fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'geos_c.h': No such file or directory

I cannot understand why if 0.18.0 is the primary version of [cartopy in conda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/cartopy), it tries to install a previous version. In Anaconda navigator there is also the old version (0.17.0). I'm using Anaconda for Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Something about the environment that you're trying to install it in must be blocking it. I'd first try to check it with a new environment:

```
conda create -n test_env python=3.8 cartopy=0.18
```